# Using a specific network interface for a WININET HTTP request

Tags: windows, http, wininet

Is there a way to specify which local network interface to use when using the WININET interface for an outgoing HTTP request?

I know how to do it with WINSOCK (using bind()), but I can't find an equivalent way to do it using WININET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinInet does not support specifying the local address or port to use for TCP connections.